# How can I manage a .csv import in R where intended numeric columns include non-numeric data?

Tags: r, csv, gps, numeric

I have a dataset of GPS locations (x), and there are occasional NA values in the dataset. When applying a read.csv command, the GPS lat/long values (in UTM meters) are imported as a factor class, with each GPS value as a level.

To convert back to numbers, I have attempted to use the

```
print(x$lat, quotes = F)
```

command to remove quotes. The output appears to lack quotes, but when I store it

```
x$lat <- print(x$lat, quotes = F)
```

the column is coerced into a character string. This is a good first step, but the quotes are retained in the character string. Normally, I read that applying the following function usually works for removing non-numeric data

```
x$lat <- x$lat[!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(x$lat)))]
```

However, because the quotes are retained, none of the data are entirely "numeric", and so the `!is.na(...)` part returns a vector completely filled with `FALSE` values, and the resulting vector is `NA` of length `x$lat`.

I also copied this string to attempt to remove the quotes from the character vector that I can make, to no avail.

```
x$lat <- gsub("\\'", "", x$lat)
```

I suppose I could go into excel and delete the `NA` values, but I would like to learn how to manage the data effectively in R instead. T

Comment: Did you look at the na.strings option in read.csv? With the good values, you may be able to read your file directly as number.

Comment: Don't fix the symptom. Find out why those columns are coerced to factors.

Comment: @Roland, thank you for your comments. I excised all the NULL values back in the GIS software, and I am not certain why it's still being imported as a factor class. I'd inspect the dataset in the GIS, but I'm not familiar with Python at the moment; I'm working on the syntax to grab non-numeric entries at the moment.

Comment: @YCR I'll look into that; thanks! Unfortunately, I'm not sure which values are causing the column to coerce as factor. As stated before, I'm inspecting the data in the GIS to find the non-numeric values, but I must learn the proper Python syntax to do so first.

Comment: You already have the syntax for this: `x[is.na(as.numeric(as.character(x$lat))),]`.

Comment: @Roland, I applied the following Python script to assess numeric entries

    `def is_number(s):  
        try:  
            float(s)  
            return True  
        except ValueError:  
            return False`  

Using the 'Get Unique Values' function in the GIS, I return all TRUE values, indicating there are no non-numeric entries.

Comment: Why do you use python to investigate why R fails to recognize numbers? It seems more prudent to me to investigate it within R.

Comment: @Roland, The original data are from a table in ArcGIS, so the numbers are actual number values there. In R, the problem is that I can't analyze the "numbers" because they exist within quotes; I can't ask whether any value in the dataset in R is a number because none of them technically are. This is the core issue; I want  to convert the datasets in R so that they are numeric, and at the moment the import fails to do so. I am attempting to do as you suggested and find out why the columns are coerced to factors instead of fixing the symptom.

Comment: Please share `dput(droplevels(x$lat[1:n]))` with an appropriate `n`.